# Rotating data by angle theta

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, rotation, rotational-matrices

Might be a simple question but let's say you have 2d normal data that you want to rotate 90 degrees counter clockwise, to do this you can use [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and construct one with `theta = np.pi / 2` and then multiply the data by your rotation matrix. That works great, however when I try to rotate the data 45 degrees (`np.pi / 4`), it does not work. It appears to have rotated the data clockwise, but flipping the sign of the angle does not change the resulting plot. How can I rotate the data 45 degrees counterclockwise?

```
cov = np.array([[1, .7], [.7, 1]])
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(2), cov, size=10000)
theta = np.pi / 4
rot_matrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)],
                       [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])
data_rot = (rot_matrix @ data.T).T
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2)
axes[0].scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])
axes[1].scatter(data_rot[:, 0], data_rot[:, 1])
fig.show()
```

yields the image:

[image]

(whereas I expected a 45 counterclockwise rotation to make the data look like a vertical line) while changing the theta to `np.pi / 2` yields the correct image of:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rotation matrix is correct. It's the auto scaling from matplotlib that is making look as though the rotation is wrong. Try adding these before `fig.show()`

```
axes[0].set_aspect("equal")
axes[1].set_aspect("equal")
```

Comment: Thank you, that showed me what I wanted to see!